# Git doesn't "see" App_Data in ASP.NET MVC4 web application

Tags: git

I was musing about whether to include the `App_Data` directory (of my ASP.NET MVC4 web application) in its [git](/questions/tagged/git) repository when I noticed that it is already being ignored, even when there is no `.gitignore` file at all.

This is a new application that I just created and immediately initialized a repo. I tried creating another new application (from Visual Studio 2012), and got the same result. I also tried simply initializing a [git](/questions/tagged/git) repo in a directory that I manually created. Here are my results (from bash prompt):

*I'm on Windows 7 running msysgit with git version 1.8.1.2.*

```
$ mkdir TEST

$ cd TEST

$ mkdir App_Data

$ ls
App_Data/

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Projects/TEST/.git/

$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

$ echo wtf...
```

**Why is [git](/questions/tagged/git) ignoring the `App_Data` directory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is ignoring the App_Data directory because it is empty. Git works based on files rather than folders so ignores empty directories. A standard way to store an empty directory is to place a `.gitignore` or `readme` file in the folder and commit that.

Answer (score 1):

Please mark above post as answer if that solved your issue.

I was having same problem, my repo was ignoring App_Data folder, where my database file (.sdf) was located. I tried adding .gitignore and it still did not work. I had to sync .sdf file so I did this,

- Opened .gitignore
- Find file type that you DO NOT want git to IGNORE (in my case the line was ' *.sdf ')
- Remove the lines of your required file types, save the file.

Now your App_Data and its files/sub-directories should be visibe in repo.